# how can export material-ui table to CSV?

Tags: reactjs, csv, export, material-ui

someone of you can explain me how to export a material-ui-table to CSV file ?

```
 <Paper> 
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>

            <TableCell>A</TableCell>
            <TableCell >B</TableCell>
            <TableCell>C</TableCell>
            <TableCell>D</TableCell>

        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {this.rows.map(row => {
            return (
                <TableRow key={row.ID}>
                  <TableCell>{row.A}   </TableCell>
                  <TableCell >{row.B}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.C}</TableCell>   
                  <TableCell >{row.D}</TableCell>                
                </TableRow>
            );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </Paper>
```

I need to create a component that exports this table to csv format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Material-UI's [tables page 'Complementary projects' section](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#complementary-projects) they recommend on using [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table).

One of material-table's props is `exportButton={true}`, which renders a CSV Export button.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to roll your own solution you can use `filefy` which is what [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) uses under the hood

```
npm i --save filefy
```

then

```
import { CsvBuilder } from 'filefy';
//...
const builder = new CsvBuilder('filename.csv');
builder
  .setDelimeter(',')
  .setColumns(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ])
  .addRows(data)
  .exportFile();
```

`rows` is an array of arrays, e.g.

```
const rows = [
                [ 'r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3', 'r1c4'],
                [ 'r2c1', 'r2c2', 'r2c3', 'r2c4'],
]
```

There is a bit of a disconnect here as a `<TableCell>` can contain jsx inside of it (even tho it does not in your case) so you cannot simply 'dump' the data from the `<Table>` as it may not be plain text.

If you have simple string values like in your case it may be suitable to define a `string[][]` that can be used for both your jsx **and**  `CsvBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can export all the data using exportAllData: true  , no need filefy

```
<MaterialTable
              columns={
                  columns}
                  data={data}
                  title="Export all"
          
            options={{
            exportButton: true,
            exportAllData: true
            }} >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `Table` mui component with [`Data Grid`](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/) mui component which has an [export](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/) func out of the box. This way you don't need to use another 3rd party library.